# Workspace contains Pipfile but pipenv was not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, pipenv

I am using VScode and pyenv on Mac. But each time I opened a workspace, I got this message:

> Workspace contains Pipfile but pipenv was not found. Make sure pipenv
>   is on the PATH.

My pipenv is installed and can be found using terminal on VScode.

```
>which pipenv
/Users/name/.pyenv/shims/pipenv
```

So I changed the`python.pipenvPath` setting to `/Users/name/.pyenv/shims`. This time I got:

> Workspace contains Pipfile but '/Users/user/.pyenv/shims' was not
>   found. Make sure '/Users/user/.pyenv/shims' is on the PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because current workspace cannot find your pipenv path. So create a settings.json under .vscode and point to the correct pipenv path.

To find pipenv path, go to your folder with pipenv file,

> pipenv --py
>   /Users/[username]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[app-NVz65APH]/bin/python

and then modify settings.json:

> "python.pythonPath":
>   "/Users/[username]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[app-NVz65APH]/bin/python",