# How can I work on a django project in my external harddrive

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pip, pipenv

I have an external drive from my old PC and I would like to continue working on some projects there, I have set up python but on my VSCode I keep getting "workspace contains pipfile but pipenv was not found". What's the solution to this?

Comment: The same question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280597/workspace-contains-pipfile-but-pipenv-was-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workspace contains Pipfile but pipenv was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61280597/workspace-contains-pipfile-but-pipenv-was-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You should first install pipenv to your machine eg:

```
pip install pipenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual env in the folder you'll be working in. Install Django together with other dependencies you'll be using. Wallah you're ready to start working.